# How to export structure member

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to know that how can i access name member in my driver/driver.c
Here is the code from include/linux/cpufreq.h

```
struct cpufreq_governor {
    char    name[CPUFREQ_NAME_LEN];
    int     (*governor) (struct cpufreq_policy *policy,
                 unsigned int event);
    ssize_t (*show_setspeed)    (struct cpufreq_policy *policy,
                     char *buf);
    int     (*store_setspeed)   (struct cpufreq_policy *policy,
                     unsigned int freq);
    unsigned int max_transition_latency; /* HW must be able to switch to
            next freq faster than this value in nano secs or we
            will fallback to performance governor */
    struct list_head    governor_list;
    struct module       *owner;
};
```

driver.c has a function which depends on active governor.So how to take it as variable in driver.c

Comment: What do you need the name of the active governor for? (And what if the CPUs have different governors?)

Comment: @CL. There is only one CPU.btw the reason for doing this is that in my driver there are some functions which will increase CPU freq in special cases.but it behaves same on powersave governor also, where CPU freq must be minimum but it increases it. Thats why i need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cpufreq exports symbol `cpufreq_get_policy` with which you can get policy. `cpufreq_policy` has a member `governor`. This is what you are looking for.

Comment: I added following lines to a function in my driver
[formatted link to pastebin](http://pastebin.com/m3GVviB6)
but driver hangs upon execution of that function.Nothing is print on dmesg.

Comment: How do you get data in `gov_info`? I think, you are accessing unallocated region

Comment: i did somethings wrong.Sorry but i'm not much experienced.I just added those lines.I will be glad if you suggest me a way to save correct value in is_powersave variable.

Comment: I'm not experienced in kernel programming at all. But you should create a variable with type `struct spufreq_policy`, then call cpufreq's function `cpufreq_get_policy` and pass in pointer to you variable and number of cpu you want to get policy for. Then you can access governor through the `governor` field. And your could get governor's name with `policy->governor.name`

Comment: i doubt that it'll work bcause i can only see function prototype declaration in cpufreq.h
function is originally defined in cpufreq.c

Comment: You don't need definition of function in order to call it. Just its declaration